Using Minikube: deployed SQL Server 2022, but it's not reachable on host machine using ssms
I have a Minikube running on my host machine.
For some reason I cannot connect to my containerized SQL Server from my host machine after applying the yaml scripts.
This is what I have:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mssql-secret
  namespace: new-kubernetes
type: Opaque
stringData:
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: Qwerty123!
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-service
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 30001
      targetPort: 1433
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mssql-pv
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/mssql"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-pvc
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest  # MSSQL Server 2022
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql-secret
              key: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssql-data
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssql-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-pvc

kubectl get all -n new-kubernetes:
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mssql-deployment-5d8d4b4bc7-v7szb    1/1     Running   0          28s

NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
service/mssql-service       LoadBalancer   10.108.132.45   127.0.0.1     30001:31453/TCP   28s

NAME                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mssql-deployment    1/1     1            1           28s

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mssql-deployment-5d8d4b4bc7    1         1         1       28s

Minikube tunnel:
W0903 20:18:09.098870   73348 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\XXXXXXX\.docker\contexts\meta\XXXXXXX\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
* Tunnel successfully started

* NOTE: Please do not close this terminal as this process must stay alive for the tunnel to be accessible ...

* Starting tunnel for service mssql-service.

kubectl describe pod mssql-deployment-5d8d4b4bc7-v7szb -n new-kubernetes:
....
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  4m8s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned new-kubernetes/mssql-deployment-5d8d4b4bc7-v7szb to minikube
  Normal  Pulled     4m8s  kubelet            Container image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    4m8s  kubelet            Created container mssql
  Normal  Started    4m8s  kubelet            Started container mssql

SSMS
Server name: localhost,30001
Authentication: SQL Server authentication
Login: sa
Password: Qwerty123!
Encryption: Mandatory
[V] Trust server certificate

SSMS error message:

Cannot connect to localhost,30001.
Additional information:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
This server was not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225)

I can't seem to figure out if I have a configuration error or why this doesn't work. Maybe someone could help with why I cannot connect with SQL Server Management Studio to my containerized SQL Server?

Configuration mismatch in volumes, here's the solution I'm currently using:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostname: mssqlinst
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
      containers:
      - name: mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: "Developer"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql-secret
              key: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssqldb
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-data
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mssql-data
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /data/mssql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-service
  namespace: new-kubernetes
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
  selector:
    app: mssql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: mssql-secret
    namespace: new-kubernetes
type: Opaque
stringData:
    MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: Qwerty123!

Why were the yaml files incorrect?
Persistent Volume wasn't linked to Persistent Volume Claim (mssql-pv to mssql-pvc) due to a missing volumeName-field or the that the names weren't the same. So renaming the mssql-pvc to mssql-pv in the yaml from the question would have also sufficed.
More detailed explanation:
In the following explanation I will only list the important fields for the answer to make it more clearly what happened and why the Persistent Volume Claim could not find it's Persistent Volume.
First you declare a Volume Mount:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumeMounts:
      - name: mssqldb

Then you link the Volume Mount to a Persistent Volume Claim:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-data


Note: mssqldb now references the volumeMount.


Note: mssqldb now requests a Persistent Volume Claim named mssql-data.

Then you declare a Persistent Volume Claim named "mssql-data":
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-data

Finally you declare a Persistent Volume named "mssql-data":
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mssql-data


Note: mssqldb now references the Persistent Volume Claim (same name).

What if you want to have a different name for the Persistent Volume?
Make the following changes in the Persistent Volume Claim:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-data
spec:
  volumeName: mssql-data-new-name

Finally give the Persistent Volume the desired name:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mssql-data-new-name


Note: mssql-data-new-name now references the Persistent Volume Claim (defined in the Persistent Volume Claim).

Remarks:
Notice that Kubernetes/Docker didn't log anything that made this clear.
So my recommendation would be to either always explicitly name your Persistent Volume in the Persistent Volume Claim or always keep the names the same as shown in the snippets above.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
